# tableView vs. scrollView behavior when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, keyboard

If a textfield opens keyboard and textfield is member of a tableView, then it will be able to scroll tableView to be able to see the last item, and keyboard will not hide that item.

[image]

How? UITableView is inherited from UIScrollView. I guess opening keyboard increases the content offset? Am I right?

If textfield is part of a scrollView, not a tableView, this effect will not occur, and it keyboard can hide out other controls positioned lower parts of the scrollView.

If I want to see the same effect with scrollView as with tableView, should I set content offset manually?

[image]

Comment: Hey Janos maybe you also find more helpful answers and insights here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to set your content offset  manually .

First you register for the notification

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

And then in your observer methods.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification){

    var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
    keyboardFrame = self.view.convertRect(keyboardFrame, fromView: nil)

    var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = self.scrollView.contentInset
    contentInset.bottom = keyboardFrame.size.height
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification:NSNotification){

    var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
}
```

Comment: Beside I am setting `contentInset`, can I set `contentSize` too? They are independent right?

Answer (score 0):

You can import TPKeyboardAvoiding class downloaded from https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding and set the UITableView class to TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView.